# Converting excel files to UTF-8 .TSV

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, csv, encoding, utf-8

Every week I have to convert 25 or more Excel files to **UTF-8 .tsv files**. As of now I'm doing it using Editplus application manually.

I was searching  Google and other sites where I'm getting UTF-8 .csv conversion only.

Is there a way to automate this?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to have each worksheet open in Excel, then you SAVE AS Unicode Text (*.txt), and finally renaming that text file from .txt to .tsv

*EDIT:* If your Excel version giving you ANSII, then you just need to change your encoding in Web Options. In the same SAVE AS dialog, after choosing Unicode Text, click on Tools > Web Options > Encoding, then select Unicode (UTF-8).
[image: Excel Web Options]

Comment: No the above method saving file in ANSII not in UTF-8

Comment: Which version of Excel do you have? And what is your Region set as in Windows?

Comment: Office 365 region India.. Tried the above but its not working

Comment: Also i need .TSV not in .txt

Comment: .TSV = .txt, so like I mentioned in the answer you rename to .TSV, this is tested on Office 365 region India and it works using the mentioned Web Options.

Comment: Thank you. This idea is not working for me as im trying to reduce manual work...

Comment: I tried the above method and it didnt produce the result I wanted (UTF-8).  I opened Excel's output unicode file in VS Code, and the VSC guessed the file as UTF-16. Using VSC, I saved it from UTF-16 -> UTF-8  using `>Change File Encoding` and `>Save`  action